# How to exploit the Sony Direct-rR-Bravia mode with windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, tv

I bought a new TV (Sony) and I set it in WiFi direct mode. On my laptop, I see a Direct-rR-Bravia wireless connexion.
I set the key and tried to connect to it. The link switchs continuously between **connected** and **limited connexion**.
After a google phase, it seems that My laptop is too old for using Wi-Fi Direct mode.
My OS is Windows 7 Enterprise, the Intel WiFi adapter is 5300AGN.
I did:
- restart windows media player network sharing service,
- restart Upnp service,
- there is no STREAM tab in windows media player,
- Turning on media streaming in Network&Sharing center has no effect,
- Installation of the my wifi dashboard application display "adapter not found",
- Uninstall and install WMP has no effect (no stream button).

I have many movies on my laptop and I am looking for a workaround for visualize them on my TV. Any Ideas I didn't found ?

Comment: Could you developp your idea please ? I want a wireless link. Shall I configure W7 as an hotspot ?

Comment: I have a laptop, no router ! Sony KDL-40r555c for the TV. Didn't find a browser on TV but I also configured a build-in wireless, gave an IP address to my TV in the same range that my laptop on which I created an hotspot. What can I do now ?

Comment: Strange dialog since a guy has deleted his answers !